# Run product with maven tycho before executing tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I have a plugin which contains tests. The pom.xml file looks like this:

```
  <artifactId>org.sample.test</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
  <name>minicrm - client.test</name>
```

bevore executing the tests, I want to start my server.product. How can I tell maven to start the server product before?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the server.product to be started as a separate process, or do you want to have the tests executed within the product?

Comment: more detailled, the tests I want to execute require that the server is running. therefore I need to start the server.product before

Comment: Do the tests need to be executed in an OSGi container? If not, you may be able to use the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: Yes, I need an osgi container

Comment: In this case, try to start the server using normal JUnit functionality, e.g. `@BeforeClass` or a `@RunWith`.